# Unable to start Kylin in HDP 2.4

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, kylin

Tried to install Kylin using the [documentation](http://kylin.apache.org/docs15/install/) . I was able to start kylin and execute sample.sh. But I was not able to use web UI. Please find below the error message.

I am using Kylin apache-kylin-1.5.2.1-HBase1.x-bin.tar.gz and hbase 1.1.2.2.4.Kindly help to resolve this issue.

```
    [hdfs@ip-10-0-2-62 apache-kylin-1.5.2.1-bin]$ cat logs/kylin.out
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.10.0-30/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.10.0-30/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hdfs/apache-kylin-1.5.2.1-bin/lib/kylin-jdbc-1.5.2.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hdfs/apache-kylin-1.5.2.1-bin/lib/kylin-job-1.5.2.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
usage: java org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina [ -config {pathname} ] [ -nonaming ]  { -help | start | stop }
Jul 26, 2016 11:39:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: :/usr/hdp/2.4.10.0-30/hadoop/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64:/usr/hdp/2.4.10.0-30/hadoop/lib/native
Jul 26, 2016 11:39:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-7070"]
Jul 26, 2016 11:39:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-7070"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:7070
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:411)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:646)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:677)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:398)
        ... 23 more


Jul 26, 2016 11:39:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-7070]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-7070]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:677)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:7070
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:411)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:646)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:398)
        ... 23 more


Jul 26, 2016 11:39:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-9009"]
Jul 26, 2016 11:39:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 900 ms
Jul 26, 2016 11:39:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 26, 2016 11:39:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.59
Jul 26, 2016 11:39:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /home/hdfs/apache-kylin-1.5.2.1-bin/tomcat/webapps/kylin.war
Jul 26, 2016 11:39:21 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/usr/hdp/2.4.10.0-30/hbase/lib/ojdbc6.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/hdp/2.4.10.0-30/hbase/lib/ojdbc6.jar (No such file or directory)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:154)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:91)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.FileUrlJar.<init>(FileUrlJar.java:41)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:34)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig$FragmentJarScannerCallback.scan(ContextConfig.java:2647)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:258)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1902)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1272)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5412)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Jul 26, 2016 11:39:21 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/usr/hdp/2.4.10.0-30/hadoop/lib/ojdbc6.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/hdp/2.4.10.0-30/hadoop/lib/ojdbc6.jar (No such file or directory)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:154)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:91)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.FileUrlJar.<init>(FileUrlJar.java:41)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:34)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig$FragmentJarScannerCallback.scan(ContextConfig.java:2647)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:258)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1902)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1272)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5412)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Jul 26, 2016 11:39:21 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/home/hdfs/apache-kylin-1.5.2.1-bin/mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/hdfs/apache-kylin-1.5.2.1-bin/mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar (No such file or directory)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:154)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:91)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.FileUrlJar.<init>(FileUrlJar.java:41)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:34)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig$FragmentJarScannerCallback.scan(ContextConfig.java:2647)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:258)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1902)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1272)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5412)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your 7070 is already in use.

You can check it by using `netstat -anp|grep 7070`

I solved this by replaced 7070 with a new unused port in `kylin/tomcat/conf/server.xml`

`<Connector port="7090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   redirectPort="7443"
                   compression="on"
                   compressionMinSize="2048"`